# extraer un dato de un js con expresión regular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Necesito acceder a un state.js y sacar la ruta 'dictionary' a una variable para luego usar en otra funcion, he intentado con expresion regular pero no he logrado el resultado esperado.

Gracias.

Esto es lo que hice

```
let re = /dictionary/g;
let dictionary = state.match(re);
```

state.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

states.push({
    'parent': 'app',
    'name': 'test',
    'url': '/test',
    'views': {
        'ui-view@app': {
            'templateUrl': 'test/html/test.html',
            'controller': 'testCtrl'
        }
    },
    'dependencies': ['test/js/test.js'],
    'dictionary': 'test/i18n/messages.json'
});

}());
```

Comment: ¿qué expresión regular intentaste?

Comment: @fedorqui utlice la siguiente que me devuelve solo dictionary si lo encuentra mas no la ruta. let re = /dictionary/g;
        let dictionary = state.match(re);

Comment: pero siendo como es un JSON, ¿no puedes acceder al valor por su índice?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Contenido del archivo state.js

const data = `(function() {
'use strict';

states.push({
    'parent': 'app',
    'name': 'test',
    'url': '/test',
    'views': {
        'ui-view@app': {
            'templateUrl': 'test/html/test.html',
            'controller': 'testCtrl'
        }
    },
    'dependencies': ['test/js/test.js'],
    'dictionary': 'test/i18n/messages.json'
});

}());`

//Expresión
let re = /'dictionary'\s*:\s*'([^']+)'/
//'dictionary': Empieza la coincidencia con?
//\s*: Halla espacios o no entre la llave y valor
//(   ): Encapsula la coincidencia
//' : El valor empieza con una comilla simple
//[^']+: Coincidir cualquier valor hasta encontrar la segunda comilla simple

//Búsqueda
let dictionary = data.match(re);  

//Comprueba si encontró, e imprimir el valor encontrado
console.log("URL Dictionary >> ", dictionary ? dictionary[1] : 'No encontrado')
```